# Best solution for iOS Mapping multiple latitude and longitude points

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapping, apple-maps

What would be my best option if i want to map multiple lat, longs onto a map within an iOS App?

I have hundreds of points captured from a GPS receiver over an hours walk. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to best ingest all these points and spit out a map with the exact route followed??

Any help with this would be great. Is there anyway i can provide all the data points to the Google Maps API and they return a map plus meta data for things like total distance?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? What part are you unsure about? How do you want to display the route and when?

As far as I understand, you are saving coordinates to a database at a defined interval. We don't know at what frequency. You will be able to display each point on a map, and eventually link them alltogether with a polyline. But that won't follow roads. For this you would need to use the [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). But this service has limitations:

1. You cannot assume that giving the service your start and end coordinates it would calculate the same route that you followed.
2. You can give the service a few waypoints but you are limited to 8 waypoints per request (with the free API).
3. The free API allows for 2500 requests per day / 10 per second.

Let me know if there is anything else I can help you with.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. The frequency of points would be every 30 seconds. I would be sending these to my own API which in turn would be storing them in our DB. I would want the line to go to point A then draw a line to point B then to point C then point D etc. This would continue for an hour. I would be using the paid API

Comment: Well then it will be easier. You can use a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple). You don't need the Maps API for Business to achieve that, except if you would have a lot of map loads, or maybe you have other functionalities in mind.